# $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{|(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)|}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I need to find the integrals $$\int _{-\infty}^{a_1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{|(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)|}},$$
$$\int _{a_2}^{a_3}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{|(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)|}}$$
$a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}: a_1<a_2<a_3.$

I tried to solve it using different substitution such as $u^2=t-a_3$ and $tan(\psi) =u/\sqrt{a_3-a_1}$. But it doesn't work...

Thank you for any help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527080/integrability-of-a-polynomial-under-root/3535857#3535857

Comment: As it happens, they're equal to each other. Perhaps you'll find [this](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~faris/methodsweb/branch.pdf) helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first integral, substitute $ x = a_3 + (a_1 - a_3)/ y^2$. For the second integral, substitute $x = a_3 + (a_2 - a_3)y^2$. In both cases, the integral you get will reduce to
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)\left(1 - \frac{a_3-a_2}{a_3 - a_1}y^2\right)}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a_3-a_1}}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{a_3-a_2}{a_3-a_1}}\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

[Elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).
If $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$,

$$
\int_{-\infty }^{{a_1}}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt { \left( {a_1}-x
 \right)  \left( {a_2}-x \right)  \left( {a_3}-x \right) }}}
\,{\rm d}x
=
{\frac {2}{\sqrt {{a_3}-{a_1}}}{\rm K}
 \left( \sqrt {{\frac {{a_3}-{a_2}}{{a_3}-{a_1}}}}
 \right) }
$$
and
$$
\int_{{a_2}}^{{a_3}}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt { \left( {a_1}-x
 \right)  \left( {a_2}-x \right)  \left( {a_3}-x \right) }}}
\,{\rm d}x={\frac {2}{\sqrt {{a_3}-{a_1}}}{\rm K}
 \left( \sqrt {{\frac {{a_3}-{a_2}}{{a_3}-{a_1}}}}
 \right) }
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I can't understand why 
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{{a_1}}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt { \left( {a_1}-x
 \right)  \left( {a_2}-x \right)  \left( {a_3}-x \right) }}}
\,{\rm d}x
=
{\frac {2}{\sqrt {{a_3}-{a_1}}}{\rm K}
 \left( \sqrt {{\frac {{a_3}-{a_2}}{{a_3}-{a_1}}}}
 \right) }
$$
where $$K(k)=\int _{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}$$

Comment: It is not a triviality.  In the 19th century, mathematicians worked out how to write elliptic integrals in terms of certain special ones, including K.  I this particular case, the method involves a conformal map from one quadrilateral to another.  In one case, the vertices are on the real axis at $\infty,a_1,a_2,a_3$;  in the other case vertices $\pm 1, \pm 1/k$.  You missed a square root $$K(k)=\int _{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}$$